# Are GREs required for US postdocs?

Tags: postdocs, united-states, gre

Do universities in the United States require GREs for postdocs in engineering?

Answer (score 24):

Typically, GREs are required for entry to graduate school, not for being hired as a postdoc.  GRE requirements are set by admissions committees who are collectively filtering a vast number of applicants with little background records.  Postdoc hiring, on the other hand, is typically handled more as an individual professor hiring an individual employee.  A particular professor might ask for GRE scores, but to the best of my knowledge that would be quite unusual, as they would typically be more interested in your thesis, publications, and other such recent and directly relevant scientific accomplishments.

Comment: Also are there any specific minimum required number of publications for postdoc..if so do you have any information? ....thank you

Comment: @jpara You seem to be under the impression that postdoctoral positions are standardized and regulated in some way.  That is not generally the case in the United States.  What a professor is looking for may vary wildly from field to field and from professor to professor.

Comment: Also note that even the GRE's being a requirement is not standard; one school (IIRC) accepted a minimum GPA from a recognized American college/university in a suitable undergraduate degree in lieu of GRE

Comment: @Foon Absolutely true, even for top schools --- [the EECS department at MIT, for example, does not even consider GRE scores](https://www.eecs.mit.edu/academics-admissions/graduate-program/faqs#15).

Comment: Also, GRE scores expire after 5 years, so typical PhD students would have to retake them to apply to post-docs. In my field, a subset of engineering melded with physics, it would be strange to see such a requirement.